# Duplicates not visible on bar graph

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have created a bar graph using a dataframe. The x-axis has duplicate values but it is not showing. I have provided the code, dataframe and bar graph below

```
car_sales.plot(x="Make", y="Odometer (KM)", kind="bar");
```

[Bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuiIK.png)

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16mDc.png)

Comment: Are you using a recent version of pandas? I can't reproduce your problem with version 1.2.1.  Also, could you add your dataframe as text (not as image), and could you show the bar graph including its labels? Note that optionally you can add a rotation in `ax = car_sales.plot(x='Make', y='Odometer', kind='bar', rot=20)`

Comment: I am using pandas 1.2.0.